Difference between &IntPtr and .ToPointer() in an unsafe context - P/Invoke
I'm working with cuDNN and using C# with P/Invoke to wrap CUDA/CuDNN functions, which requires handling pointers in an unsafe context. Specifically, I'm implementing the function to set attributes of cuDNN backend descriptors:
[LibraryImport("cudnn64_9.dll", EntryPoint = "cudnnBackendSetAttribute")]
private unsafe static partial int CudnnBackendSetAttribute(IntPtr descriptor, int attributeName, int attributeType, long elementCount, void* arrayOfElements);
public unsafe static void SetAttribute(IntPtr descriptor, CuDnnBackendAttribute attributeName, CuDnnBackendAttributeTyp attributeType, long elementCount, void* value)
{
    CudaErrorHandler.ExecuteWithCudnnErrorHandling(() => CudnnBackendSetAttribute(descriptor, (int)attributeName, (int)attributeType, elementCount, value));
}

In some of my code, I need to pass an IntPtr to the SetAttribute function as a Descriptor_t pointer. I noticed that using &IntPtr works perfectly fine, but trying to use .ToPointer() results in a runtime exception:
// Works fine
CudaDNN.SetAttribute(fpropDesc, CuDnnBackendAttribute.CUDNN_ATTR_OPERATION_CONVOLUTION_FORWARD_X, CuDnnBackendAttributeTyp.CUDNN_TYPE_BACKEND_DESCRIPTOR, 1, &xDesc);

// Causes runtime error
CudaDNN.SetAttribute(fpropDesc, CuDnnBackendAttribute.CUDNN_ATTR_OPERATION_CONVOLUTION_FORWARD_X, CuDnnBackendAttributeTyp.CUDNN_TYPE_BACKEND_DESCRIPTOR, 1, xDesc.ToPointer());

The error I get when using .ToPointer() is:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: "External component has thrown an exception."

Am I getting this right:

&IntPtr gives me the address of the IntPtr itself in managed memory.
.ToPointer() provides the pointer that IntPtr wraps, pointing to the
actual resource in unmanaged memory.

If I'm right, that using &IntPtr means I'm passing the address of a managed object, then I don't understand why the cuDNN library seems to handle it correctly and interprets it without problems. Using .ToPointer(), on the other hand, results in the exception shown above.
My Questions:

Why does using &IntPtr work here, while .ToPointer() does not?
Could it be related to how the P/Invoke marshaller or the CLR handles
IntPtr specifically?
Is there some kind of hidden mechanism that    makes &IntPtr suitable
for passing to unmanaged code, despite it    being a managed address?
Is there any best practice or deeper insight into why
IntPtr.ToPointer() might cause such an issue, especially when working
in an unsafe context with external libraries like cuDNN?

I am specifically interested in understanding why &IntPtr works fine despite pointing to managed memory, and how the CLR ensures the right behavior when interfacing with the unmanaged backend.
Thanks in advance!

Does the function you're calling expect a pointer, or does it expect a pointer to a pointer (e.g., an array of pointers)?

@MichaelLiu The function is expecting a pointer (void*) that could be a pointer to a value or a pointer to the start of an array. ElementCount tells the number of elements the pointer is pointing to and attributeType tells it what type to expect. https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/latest/api/cudnn-graph-library.html#cudnnbackendsetattribute

There's something very odd here about using IntPtr and void* side by side; they express the same concept!

@MarcGravell Thank you for your input. If IntPtr is basically a void* then it could somehow explain how it works, since IntPtr is Blittable, so the structure of it should be the same in managed and unmanaged memory, I guess.
In the documentation it states that a void* is expected. The function is very general and used to set many diffrent types of values.

i.ToPointer() is just defined as (void*)i (* in .NET is only usable in unsafe-marked code while IntPtr is more for managed/safe code) which is of course different than &i, which is the address of i (also only usable only in unsafe code).

@Kiwimanshare What is xDesc initialized to? Do you know what the equivalent C code should be?

@MichaelLiu Within the API xDesc is a cudnnBackendDescriptor_t. From the Doku:
"cudnnBackendDescriptor_t is a typedef void pointer to one of many opaque descriptor structures. The type of structure that it points to is determined by the argument when allocating the memory for the opaque structure using cudnnBackendCreateDescriptor()." - https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/latest/api/cudnn-graph-library.html#cudnnbackenddescriptor-t
In C:
cudnnBackendSetAttribute(fpropDesc, CUDNN_ATTR_OPERATION_CONVOLUTION_FORWARD_X, CUDNN_TYPE_BACKEND_DESCRIPTOR, 1, &xDesc)

@Kiwimanshare yes, void* and IntPtr are basically identical - IntPtr is just a shim struct of the same size that wraps a single void* field and makes it easier to use in code without requiring unsafe (which isn't even available in some .NET languages, and is disallowed by policy in some other contexts); this means that void* and IntPtr are indeed blittable in either direction (as long as that's a direct blit and not a dereference)

@MarcGravell Okay, I see. Does it matter in which "memory-contex" the IntPtr is set? In my case IntPtr is set by an Invoke-Function via "out".
When I output "&intptr" and "intptr.ToPointer()" I get 2 diffrent adresses. The strange thing is, that "&intptr" is the correct pointer, but that should not be, since this is the pointer-adress of the wrapper-object holding the actual pointer.

ah, if it is meant to be out then yes, you're doing two very different things; "&intptr" here means "write the value to intptr", "intptr.ToPointer()" means "write the value to the deferenced endpoint of intptr"; this is again: void**

@MarcGravell Thank you! So if I get this right: Since I work with out, the unmanaged function can write its 'value' directly into the managed memory and therefore using &IntPtr works since the memorystructure is correct and as expected?

yes; if this is basically (in casual terms) out void*, then that's the same thing (again, in casual terms) as void**, which &somePtr will satisfy; honestly, if your code is already using unsafe, I'd probably urge you to use void* or ideally SomeUnmanagedStruct* in place of IntPtr - it'll be clearer

@MarcGravell would you mind reviewing my Answer to the Question, if that is OK for you, before I mark it as accepted? I don't want to spread wrong informations.
